# Kill [external]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[external](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/external) (3100+ Questions, 21 Watchers) does not sound useful. It needs some killing.

Comment: 1,828 questions tagged.  That's going to take awhile.  Is your fiendish plan to keep finding these tags and asking these questions until SE relents and gives us better tools?

Comment: I think that's a good goal :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't understand. Are you tired of my Questions?

Comment: Do you understand what you're asking for when you ask these questions?  The tags have to be removed from questions *one at a time.*  That means that 1,828 edits have to occur to remove this tag.  Personally, I think there are better ways to spend that time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it takes less time if more people help.

Comment: @RobertHarvey do you not find it worthy to help clean-up the site by removing not-very-useful tags?

Comment: I'm guessing you're asking for about 9 hours of labor, if it takes 15 seconds to remove each tag.  That doesn't count the additional effort it will take to review each question for other defects, which seems to be the way the community wants these things handled.  That easily accounts for another, say, 27 hours of labor.

Comment: @Robert, do you mean it does not scale? I usually don't act on tag-related meta-questions, but I was under the impression they were always dismissed or handled. Are you saying only a few users take care of the bulk of the work?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Of the 59 burninate requests I see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request?page=4&sort=votes&pagesize=50), two of them are marked [status-completed].

Comment: Your question is always *"Tag [xyz] does not sound useful...can we kill it?"*. **You never provide any real analysis of the tag**. Take the current one for example - have you checked that the term is not valid when used with other tags (like qt or css)? In summary: **please provide analysis!** Especially on tags used as widely as this. You are quite possibly right, but you need to show that you are right.

Comment: @slugster In many cases it should be obvious, so no need for analysis. I see many people putting (too) much detail in simple Questions like this. If there are rebuttals, they should be in Comments/Answers, and/or expressed as Downvotes.

Comment: Some of the ones you post are obvious (and not frequently used). This one has been used quite extensively (rightly or wrongly), so we need to make sure it doesn't have some meaning. We can't rely on "the right people" seeing your meta post and answering, so you need to show you've done the research to find it isn't useful.

Comment: @slugster because posts that are longer seem more credible, even if the extra length is not needed? I thought this one was also obvious, so no need to justify the request.

Comment: I'm not sure what research is required here.  Click on the tag.  There seems to be no similarity amongst any of the questions except for "something" being "external" to "something else".  It's about as redundant as having a `code` tag.

Comment: Post length isn't important, but credibility is critical. This tag clearly needs a clean up but you need to prove it when it comes to requests for burnination. Software Dev is a deep complex world, terms like this can be in use without you being aware of it. The only things obvious are tags like 'spaghetti-monster', and even then someone could come out with a product called that which suddenly means it is valid.

Comment: @Cypher Here's a not-as-contrived-as-it-seems analogy: you have a plot of land that is infested with a particular type of weed. It's obviously weed, no doubt about it. You annihilate that weed with some weedkiller. Then you find you've removed the only food source for a small animal *you had no idea existed*. It's the same with this - *obvious* is not synonymous with *correct*. When you check the detail sometimes *obvious* becomes *downright wrong*. That's what we need to check for. I'm simply asking Tshepang to show he's done the requisite research.

Comment: @slugster in that case, it may not be such a loss since you didn't even know that animal existed. That's unless it was useful in some way you were not aware of, or that eliminating it was somehow immoral (even if you didn't know it existed). In that case, aren't we going to say it was a worthy risk, and we learned the hard way? Is it not the case that we do not have the will and/or resources to thoroughly study the consequences of our actions?

Comment: @Robert I don't get it... Can't you just use mod tag burnintation tool?..

Comment: @nicael: There is no such tool.

Answer (score 12):

I agree. What is external? This tag says nothing about the question.

When you're using the tag [external](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/external), you're likely using *something* that is external. So why not just re-tag it as [*something*] or [external- *something*]?

Let it burn.