# We should keep [internal]/[external] internally to ourselves

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

These seem a bit odd. Our questions shouldn't matter if something is internal or external.

[internal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internal) is defined as

> The Internal tag should be used when the question in which this tag has been used is about internal operation in a program/function/language/system.. e.g.

[external](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/external) is defined as

> This tag refers to something that is outside of a particular system. In other words, it is something that is not a part of the main system and therefore can be considered "extra".

Comment: ... Can you phrase that in the form of a pun?

Comment: @AKHolland i tried.

Comment: Would `externalize [external] and [internal]` work?

Comment: half-possible half-duplicate [Kill \[external\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254893)

Comment: @AKHolland - Don't be a pun in the a$$

Comment: There is also the [tag:internals] tag

Comment: Why on earth do people make such silly tags?

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit They're probably used to other sites having a "liberal" tag system (i.e., *put-whatever-you-want-there*), or worse, their blogs (blog tags reach really ridiculous levels of uselessness sometimes).